# Contar valores únicos entre dos columnas en pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Quiero hacerles una consulta, lo que pasa es que quiero contar los clientes de un dataframe de ventas en pandas, pero no puedo hacerlo con el método df.nombres.value_counts() porque me contaría los nombres y cuantas veces se repite cada uno es decir si un cliente tiene el nombre de otro lo tomaría como el mismo
Adicionalmente tengo dos columnas la de nombre y apellido[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: crea una columna `fullname` y entonces aplicas el conut a esa columna

Answer (score 1):

lo logre creando una nueva columna llamada nombre completo, pero antes es necesario pasar todo el dataframe a minusculas asi:

```py
df=df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.lower()) #esta linea lo que hace es pasar todas las columnas de mi dataframe a minuscula
```

Porque al contar los nombres completos, python diferencia entre mayúsculas y minúsculas, por lo tanto si escribe `Miguel` o `miguel`, lo va a tomar como alguien diferente.

por ultimo creo la nueva columna así:

```py
df['nombre completo']=df['nombres'].astype(str)+' '+df['apellidos'].astype(str)#creando la columna llamada nombre copleto
```